# How to make websocket authentication with Nginx. (I'm using JWT with "auth_request" module)

Tags: security, nginx, jwt

How to authenticate websocket with Nginx?
When I setup "auth_request" module in Nginx, the server is not getting the request delivered and Chrome outputs:

> WebSocketSubject.ts:259 WebSocket connection to
> 'ws://localhost/ws/videos' failed: HTTP Authentication failed; no valid
> credentials available

This is my setup:

```
#client
upstream client {
    server localhost:3000;
}

upstream authentication {
    server localhost:4000; 
}

upstream rtserver {
    server localhost:6000;
}

server {
    listen        80;
    listen        [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/guy/Documents/workspace/project/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client/; 
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client/sockjs-node;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }   
 
    location /ws/videos { 
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;

        proxy_pass http://rtserver/ws/videos;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 

        proxy_set_header Set-Cookie $cookie_video;

        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol $http_sec_websocket_protocol;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions $http_sec_websocket_extensions;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Version $http_sec_websocket_version;
    } 

    location = /users/login {
        proxy_pass http://authentication/users/login/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
    }

    location /users {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_pass http://authentication/users/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://authentication/auth/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    }

    error_page  404  /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

thanks for helpers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution

I finally figured out how to solve this websocket - jwt problem with nginx.
there are some bad suggestions:

1. using the basic auth mechanism for delivering the token which is not recommended and also stripped out in some browsers.
2. leverage the protocol (second argument) of websockets in order to deliver the token to the server safely to the server together with "proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol $http_sec_websocket_protocol;" on the Nginx side.
   it's is also not recommended because it's kind of a hack.

**The best solution:**
Remove the line: "auth_request /auth" from Nginx because now the check will be made inside the upgrade route of the upstream server (e.g NodeJS).

**The interaction:**

1. Client send an "upgrade" + cookie(with JWT).
2. Nginx passes the request along with the jwt cookie by using: "proxy_set_header Set-Cookie $cookie_[cookie name];"
3. now, when the request arrived to the NodeJS "upgrade": send a GET sub-request to /auth in order to verify the token. (you can use "node-fetch" library)
   if you get status 200, then token is verified and you can connect the websocket, otherwise close the connection.

Summarize: We have seen how to incorporate Websockets with JWT authentication by simply moving the /auth sub-request from Nginx to the NodeJS service. also, we had to do another step of accepting the upgrade.

Those are the main parts of the code:

**NodeJS "upgrade" route:**

```
server.on("upgrade", function upgrade(req, sock, head) {
  const pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
  if (pathname === "/ws/video") {
    fetch("http://localhost/auth/", {
      headers: {
        Authorization: req.headers.cookie.split("=")[1]
      }
    })
      .then(resp => {
        if (!resp.ok) { 
          return;
        }
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err));

    wss.handleUpgrade(req, sock, head, function done(ws) {
      wss.emit("connection", ws, req);
    });
  } else {
    sock.destroy();
  }
});
```

**Nginx:**
#client

```
upstream client {
    server localhost:3000;
}

upstream authentication {
    server localhost:4000; 
}

upstream rtserver {
    server localhost:6000;
}

server {
    listen        80;
    listen        [::]:80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /home/guy/Documents/workspace/project/public;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://client/; 
    }

    location /sockjs-node {
        proxy_pass http://client/sockjs-node;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }   
 
    location /ws/videos {    
        proxy_pass http://rtserver/ws/videos;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'Upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host; 

        proxy_set_header Set-Cookie $cookie_video;

        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Protocol $http_sec_websocket_protocol;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Extensions $http_sec_websocket_extensions;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Key $http_sec_websocket_key;
        proxy_set_header Sec-WebSocket-Version $http_sec_websocket_version;
    } 

    location = /users/login {
        proxy_pass http://authentication/users/login/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade; 
    }

    location /users {
        auth_request /auth;
        auth_request_set $auth_status $upstream_status;
        proxy_pass http://authentication/users/;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $remote_addr;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade; 
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location = /auth {
        internal;
        proxy_pass http://authentication/auth/;
        proxy_pass_request_body off;
        proxy_set_header Content-Length "";
        proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header Authorization $http_authorization;
    }

    error_page  404  /404.html;
        location = /40x.html {
    }

    error_page  500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
    }
}
```

Comment: trying to achieve the same also but with stomp protocol. It seems that NGINX cannot intercept the stomp header that holds the token